# Grid: Remote Data Source

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, w2ui

I'm trying to implement a **W2UI Grid** with remote datasource, I originally got it working using an aspx page returning the results.

I have since moved to an API so can pull and update data

The problem or issue I am having is constantly need to hack and slash my returned data with:
"`{\"status\":\"success\",\"total\":\"X\",\"records\":`"....

Instead of just returning IEnumerable this is causing issues with other components as I now need to duplicate logic etc

I'm hoping I'm missing something and not a flaw in W2UI always needing the status/total result first.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to require total and status to function.  Using C# I create a class that handles this more or less automatically:

```
// a few using statements that are needed
using NewtonSoft.Json;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient; 

// the class we will need to Serialize
public class w2return
{
    public string status = "success";
    public int total = 0;
    public DataTable records;
}
```

Now in your web service function, do something like:

```
w2return x = new w2return();
// write some code to return a DataTable
x.records = SomeCodeThatReturnsDataTable();
x.total = x.records.Rows.count();

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x); // this assumes your function returns a string
```

Because the serialization process wraps the whole thing in a member variable called "d", you need to parse it back out on the client side using w2ui's "parse" callback (assuming you are using jQuery):

```
parser: function (responseText) { return $.parseJSON($.parseJSON(responseText).d); }
```

Hope this helps somebody.